# Netbeans Download Javadoc repeatedly

Tags: java, caching, netbeans, javadoc

I work with Netbeans 7.0.1 for a research project. My issue is that each time I want to check the javadoc for a given function or class (from the auto-completion menu), Netbeans downloads Javadoc and caches it only while it's running. If I restart Netbeans, I have to download the javadoc again.

Is there a way to tell Netbeans to cache the Javadoc for ever?
I work with Mac OS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems strange that you download the Javadoc everytime...
To configure javadoc in Netbeans :

> Tools -> Java Platforms

Choose your JDK, the in the pane Javadoc the URL should be :

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

If you have problem with this remove it and [download the javadoc zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html) and add it instead of the url.

---

JDK8 updated link (thanks @Tim S) : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html

---

JDK 14 updated link:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-doc-downloads.html

Comment: This helped a lot, but the listed zip is no longer available. The new one is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html).

Answer (score 6):

I am using `JDK 1.8` with `Netbeans 8.0.2`.
I was also facing the same problem as Netbeans was continuously downloading the Javadoc from internet.

**I found solution to this as:**
Open Netbeans, then go to `Tools -> Java Platforms`. Then go to `Javadoc` tab and remove any URLs added for platform javadoc.
In Source tab you can add specific Javadoc from your local environment, that you can download from oracle website i.e. [Java SE 8 Doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html).
This stopped continues download of Javadoc from internet.