# Do not want to Downloading Retrieve XML

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am working on Netbeans(8.1). The probelm is every time When I start netbeans, and start for coding in FXML file then netbeans gives message Retrieve XML and nearby 15 minutes netbeans is going to be hanged. Then after I can start my work.
But if I do some GUI work like in JavaFx Scene Builder design part that time it works proparly. But when I start coding in FXML file, I have to face this Problem at every restart of IDE(netbeans).
Please give me any Suggestion if anybody knows.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658162/4148092

You can remove the Javadoc URL in the Tools section and download the .zip instead.

Comment: You either should vote to close the question as a duplicate or leave a comment, you shouldn't link to previous questions unless you're using them as a support for your own answer or providing credit for the original idea